# How to add a new item using Python Etsy HTTP API methods?

Tags: python, http

I am trying to use Etsy API to add a new listing on my store. In the documents section it says (below section how to do it). First fyi I  have never used HTTP Method before so I am not sure how to setup the code so that it adds a new item.

(Link to the Etsy API page https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listing).

```
Method Name createListing
Synopsis    Creates a new Listing.
HTTP Method POST
URI /listings
Parameters  
Name    Required    Default Type
quantity    Y       int
title   Y       string
description Y       text
price   Y       float
materials   N       array(string)
shipping_template_id    N       int
shop_section_id N       int
image_ids   N       array(int)
is_customizable N       boolean
non_taxable N       boolean
image   N       image
state   N   active  enum(active, draft)
processing_min  N       int
processing_max  N       int
category_id N       int
taxonomy_id N       int
tags    N       array(string)
who_made    Y       enum(i_did, collective, someone_else)
is_supply   Y       boolean
when_made   Y       enum(made_to_order, 2010_2017, 2000_2009, 1998_1999, before_1998, 1990_1997, 1980s, 1970s, 1960s, 1950s, 1940s, 1930s, 1920s, 1910s, 1900s, 1800s, 1700s, before_1700)
recipient   N       enum(men, women, unisex_adults, teen_boys, teen_girls, teens, boys, girls, children, baby_boys, baby_girls, babies, birds, cats, dogs, pets, not_specified)
occasion    N       enum(anniversary, baptism, bar_or_bat_mitzvah, birthday, canada_day, chinese_new_year, cinco_de_mayo, confirmation, christmas, day_of_the_dead, easter, eid, engagement, fathers_day, get_well, graduation, halloween, hanukkah, housewarming, kwanzaa, prom, july_4th, mothers_day, new_baby, new_years, quinceanera, retirement, st_patricks_day, sweet_16, sympathy, thanksgiving, valentines, wedding)
style   N       array(string)
Requires OAuth  Y
Permission Scope    listings_w
Notes   
A shipping_template_id is required when creating a listing.
All listings created on www.etsy.com must be actual items for sale. Please see our guidelines for testingwith live listings.
Creating a listing creates a single inventory products with the supplied price and quantity. Use updateInventory to add more products.
```

The code I have right know looks like this

```
import urllib
import requests
url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?api_key={YOUR KEY HERE)' # I put my API key here 
r = requests.get(url)

payload = {'quantity': '1', 'title': 'testdfsdfdfs0','description': 'dfsdfsdfsdfdsf','price': '2.55','who_made': 'i_did','is_supply': '0','when_made': '2010_2017'}
rrr = requests.post(url,payload)
print rrr # I get an error 404
```

How can I add an item for sale on Etsy through Python HTTP method?

### Update

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import json


tempory_token_url = []
oauth_response_bucket = []     
client_key = '.......'
client_secret = '......'

oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)

request_token_url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r'
fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)    
resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get('oauth_token') # Have it
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')
oauth_url_temp = tempory_token_url[0]['login_urI']
base_authorization_url = oauth_url_temp
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here: ') 
oauth_response = oauth.parse_authorization_response(redirect_response)
verifier = oauth_response.get('oauth_verifier')
access_token_url = redeirect_response 
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key=client_secret=client_secret,resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,verifier=verifier)

oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)
resource_owner_key = oauth_tokens.get('oauth_token')
resource_owner_secret = oauth_tokens.get('oauth_token_secret')
```

Any ideas how to make this work? There is very little info regarding Etsy API and most of the stuff is in PHP which I have no clue how to work.

### Image Uploading API

Everything looks the same like above this time I just changed the payload but I am getting a 403 Error. I am not sure what is causing it. My best guess would be something with oauth1.0 i think on their website it says you need oauth 1.1.

Here is how I set it up but I am getting 403 error:

```
url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings'
payload = {'listing_id':'342434342', 'image': ("test1.jpg", open('C:\\Users\\abc\\test1.jpg'),'image/jpeg'),'type':'image/jpeg'}
result = etsy.put(url, params=payload)
print result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... at this point I am lost I have no idea where to put the pin# that etsy gave me

---

> [etsy oauth#reference](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth#reference)
>   The token credentials you receive for a account do not expire,
>   and can be used over and over again to make authenticated API requests.
>   You should keep the token secret in a secure location and never send it as a plaintext parameter
>   (it's only used for signing your requests, and never needs to be sent in an API request on its own.)
>   You will not need to step through the OAuth authorization again,
>   unless you decides to revoke access, or unless you add features that require additional permission scopes.

---

> **Note**: Didn't find a equivalent Replacement for `PHP OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI`.
>   `OAuth1Session` Defaults to `signature_type=u'AUTH_HEADER'`, so this could be wrong.
>   If this fails, you could try:
>
> ```
> from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY, SIGNATURE_TYPE_BODY
> OAuth1Session(..., signature_type=SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY)
> ```

---

**Create `etsy OAuth1Session` to reuse for Requests**:

```
etsy = OAuth1Session(client_key,
                     client_secret=client_secret,
                     resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                     resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret)
```

**etsy Making an Authorized Request to the API**:

```
response = etsy.get("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/__SELF__")
user_data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

**etsy Checking Permission Scopes After Authentication**:

```
response = etsy.get("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/scopes")
meta = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

**etsy Creates a new Listing**

```
url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings'
payload = {'quantity': '1', 'title':...}
result = etsy.post(url, params=payload)
```

---

> **Comment**: for api key do I need to import oauth2

According to Reference, Yes.

> For write access and for accessing private user data, an OAuth access
>   token is required. Your application key is required to start the OAuth
>   authentication process.

```
Requires OAuth  Y
```

Also your `url` should end with

```
URI /listings

url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings'
```

---

Your url should only up to the **Question mark**, for example:

```
url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active'
payload = {'api_key':YOUR KEY HERE, 'quantity': '1', ...
rrr = requests.post(url, params=payload)
```

> Requests Quickstart: [Passing Parameters In URLs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)
>   You often want to send some sort of data in the URL's query string.
>   If you were constructing the URL by hand,
>   this data would be given as key/value pairs in the URL after a question mark,  e.g. \http://bin.org/get?key=val.
>   Requests allows you to provide these arguments as a dictionary of strings, using the params keyword argument.

Comment: for api key do I need to import oauth2 or can I use the key and secret that etsty gave me for my account. I am getting error 403. now when I want to post on my store. . I hope this question makes sense I been trying to figure this out the whole day......burned out.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am little bit stuck on the Ouath part "https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth" I have successfully complete step 1 from etsy (called -Authorizing the Request) I get a link and then I approved the request like the pictue and  it gives me a pin. at this point I am lost I have no idea where to put the pin# that etsy gave me. I will update my page so you know what I mean.

Comment: flawless explanation you are a lifesaver. Thank you

Comment: I have one more question if possible.  I am trying to upload a picture into etsy API (https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listingimage). However, I am getting a 403 error. I update page if you can please take a quick look. Again this would help me immensely with your guidance

Answer (score 4):

> **Question**: I am trying to upload a picture ... getting a 403 error

Your `url Endpoint` and  `payload` isn't correct.

> ```
> url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings'
> payload = {'listing_id':'342434342', 'image': ("test1.jpg", open('C:\\Users\\abc\\test1.jpg'),'image/jpeg'),'type':'image/jpeg'}
> ```

Steps to do a `etsy` Request(**uploadListingImage**):

1. Read the [Reference](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listingimage) for your Method Name

   > ```
   > Method Name   uploadListingImage
   > HTTP Method   POST
   > URI           /listings/:listing_id/images
   > Parameters  Name            Required    Default Type
   >         listing_id          Y                   int
   >         listing_image_id    N                   int
   >         image               N                   imagefile
   >         ...
   > Requires OAuth  Y
   > ```
   >
   > Respect Supported Sizes [Working with Images](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/images#section_uploading_images)
   >
   > **Note**: For me, it's unclear what the `image` Parameter is for.
   >   And as it's **NOT** required makes no sense.
   >   I assume its a Placeholder for the Parameter at Point 4 below: `{'image':...`
2. Build the `URI`

   ```
   uri = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/342434342/images'
   ```
3. Create the Params Dict according to the above Reference

   I recommend to use a `listing_image_id`, as this seems the only way to **delete** a Image afterwards.

   ```
   params = {'listing_id':'342434342', 'listing_image_id': 1}
   ```
4. Create **Multipart-Encoded File** Dict

   > Image uploads can be performed using a POST request with the Content-Type: [multipart/form-dataheader](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/images#section_uploading_images), following RFC1867
   >   # PHP example from [Reference](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listingimage):
   >   # $params = array('@image' => '@'.$source_file.';type='.$mimetype);

   ```
   files = {'image': ("test1.jpg", open('C:\\Users\\abc\\test1.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
   ```
5. Do the Request, according the [Reference](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listingimage), you have to use `OAuth` and `POST`

   ```
   result = etsy.post(uri, params=params, files=files)
   ```

Please Comment if this is working for you or why not.

Comment: It works!! :) I don’t know how to thank you enough. Your help was immensely appreciated and very easy to fallow/understand. Thank you again.