# How to use Etsy API credentials to GET and POST data in python

Tags: python-3.x, api, https, etsy

### Premise

I am working at linking my product configuration database with my POS and various eCommerce sites.  The last link in the puzzle is connecting to Etsy.  Their guide (https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listing) is specific to PHP, but I am working with python 3.7.

### Status

I have been able to successfully acquire the credentials required thanks to this question: [How to add a new item using Python Etsy HTTP API methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855616/how-to-add-a-new-item-using-python-etsy-http-api-methods)  I now have the following credentials:

- `oauth_token`
- `oauth_token_secret`
- `oauth_consumer_key`
- `verifier`
- `key_string`
- `shared_secret`

### What I've Tried

I tried using both `python_etsy` and `etsy_python`, but both seem to have been abandoned and are incomplete, producing exceptions at every turn.  I tried to my best ability to try to fix each issue as it arises, but am just so lost.

As suggested in the answer to the the [question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855616/how-to-add-a-new-item-using-python-etsy-http-api-methods), I tried using an `OAuth1Session` object.

```
>>> etsy = OAuth1Session(
...    key_string,
...    client_secret=shared_secret,
...    resource_owner_key=oauth_token,
...    resource_owner_secret=oauth_token_secret)
>>> esty.get('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/__SELF__')
>>> response.status_code
403
>>> response.text
'oauth_problem=token_rejected'
```

I just don't know how to properly use the given credentials in order to make successful API calls to the Etsy API.

Even adding `signature_type=SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY` when defining the `OAuth1Session` object `etsy` produces the same result.

I am posting this as a new question, since the [question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855616/how-to-add-a-new-item-using-python-etsy-http-api-methods) is specific to adding a new item using the API, while I am looking for general instruction on interpreting and converting the PHP examples for use in Python.  This is what I have done with other APIs with good success, but this particular one has thrown be for a loop.

Where does the `verifier` come in to play?

## --Update--

In place of an `oauth` session, I used `requests.get` as follows:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import uuid
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token'
>>> params = {
...  'oauth_consumer_key': {oauth_consumer_key},
...  'oauth_signature': {verifier},
...  'oauth_signature_method': {method},
...  'oauth_nonce': str(uuid(uuid1()),
...  'oauth_timestamp': datetime.timestamp(datetime.utcnow())
...  'oauth_token': {oauth_token}
...}
>>> token_response = requests.get(url,params=params)
>>> print(rrr.status_code,rrr.text)
400 oauth_problem=verifier_invalid
```

I tried the above using each of the following value for `oauth_signature_method`:

- 'PLAINTEXT'
- 'RSA-SHA1'
- 'HMAC-SHA1'

Each value produced the same result.  I also tried placing the `verifier` in the `oauth_nonce` paramater

Answer (score 2):

Use [etsy-python2](https://github.com/sscheetz/etsy-python2) module to acquire and process the credentials.

```
pip install etsy2
```

```py
from etsy2 import Etsy
from etsy2.oauth import EtsyOAuthHelper, EtsyOAuthClient
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

api_key = <etsy keystring>
shared_secret = <etsy shared secret>

#define permission scopes
permission_scopes = ['listings_r', 'listings_w']

login_url, temp_oauth_token_secret = \
    EtsyOAuthHelper.get_request_url_and_token_secret(api_key, shared_secret, permission_scopes)

query = urlparse.urlparse(login_url).query
temp_oauth_token = parse_qs(query)['oauth_token'][0]

print(login_url)
#follow the url to acquire the verifier.

oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = \
    EtsyOAuthHelper.get_oauth_token_via_verifier(api_key, shared_secret, temp_oauth_token, temp_oauth_token_secret, input('Verifier: '))

etsy_oauth = EtsyOAuthClient(client_key = api_key,
                             client_secret = shared_secret,
                             resource_owner_key = oauth_token,
                             resource_owner_secret = oauth_token_secret)

etsy = Etsy(etsy_oauth_client = etsy_oauth)
```

The `etsy2` module is current and being maintained, so right now, it is a good option.  The methods are dynamicly defined at runtime from Etsy's API server.  After defining your `Etsy` object, you can list the available methods using:

```
dir(etsy)
```